# Can't run cucumber test - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I tried to run cucumber multiple times with the use of Stackoverlow solutions solving this problem for others. It doesn't work for me.

The stacktrace I get running the runnerfile:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Lcucumber/runtime/io/ResourceLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/ClassFinder;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions;)V

at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

My  POM file

```
<groupId>selenium-siebel-new</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

My runner java class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/Resources/featurefiles",
    glue = "src/test/java/StepDefs/OpenSummaryPageStepDefs.java"
)
public class ChromeRunner {

private static ChromeDriverService service;

@BeforeClass
public static void createAndStartService() throws IOException {
    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File    ("src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe"))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();
    service.start();

}
@AfterClass
public static void createAndStopService() {
    service.stop();
}
}
```

It would be nice if someone has a solution!:)

Comment: Can you check the version of cucumber-java 1.0.0.RC14? Are you sure about this? Guessing it should be similar to the others 1.2.5

Comment: intellij added this version by itself, but changing to 1.2.5 seems to not solve it

Comment: Also the glue option you provided is not correct. You need to provide the java package instead of the actual path. in your case try something like "StepDefs"

Comment: @Grasshopper thanks for the tip! But still not able to run it. When I run the Junit example I had used from the internet (with before beforeclass test after -hooks then it is able to run. But since I try to use the RunWith it doesn't run.  I combined the before/beforeclass I had with Junit to the Beforeclass and placed it within the runner class I have now

Comment: Well the error msg says that you do not have a constructor in Runtime class with  the given parameters(resourceloader, classloader,classfinder,runtime options). I checked the code of this class in version 1.2.5 and it has this constructor. Do you have any old dependency of this such as multiple version in the hierarchy? Check the cucumber-core jar in which the class is present.

Comment: @Grasshopper   This is my library I think: https://imgur.com/a/UB81B 

Seems a bit crap. any idea what to do best? Delete all?

Comment: Seems it is mixed up with jars imported by maven as well as some you have included manually. Lot of duplication. Should keep only the maven ones. Also I am not sure why you are manually creating the chromedriverservice.

Comment: It was a sample online and this chromedriver service stuff worked before. So didn't changed it. 

Seems that maven doesn't work well.

Comment: I had to add the cucumber-core by hand because otherwise intellij didn't recognize the Cucumber.class.  verify frustrating stuff

Comment: I am not familiar with intellij but have you created a maven project to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same version of Cucumber-java dependencies as the Cucumber-JVM and Cucumber-JUnit dependencies, that is 1.2.5 in POM.xml file. This should solve the problem.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

was facing same issue.
for gradle using these two dependencies worked for me.

```
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.0'
testCompile 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues as well and i was able to resolved the issue by changing all the info-cukes-cucumber  dependencies to io.cucumber dependences

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>

   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding dependencies with same version solved my issue with #bobcat too

```
compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.2.6"
compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:4.2.6"
compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-guice:4.2.6"
compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.2.6"
```